# custom site definition template wss 3.0

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to create a custom site definition template with 'n' number of custom document libraries and content types. I have copied the ONET.xml file from the STS folder, i.e. I am trying to create a template the same as that of the OOTB Team Site template by modifying the ONET.xml but it fails.

My ONET.xml contains the default configuration with a custom master page. Inside that 
Configuration tag I am specifying my custom List as follows:

```
<Configuration ID="0" Name="Default" CustomMasterUrl="_catalogs/masterpage/samplests.master">    
<Lists>
<!-- Here I am defining a Custom List to be created with the OOTB List like Tasks -->
<List Name="SimpleList" Title="Simple List" BaseType="0" Direction="" Url="" />
</Lists>    
</Configuration>
```

Now while creating a site I select my custom template and it gives the error as follows:

```
Cannot complete this action.
Please try again.
```

Comment: Could you check out the SharePoint Logs for the specific error thrown? Also, pls post the onet.xml as we have little to nothing to go on here.

Comment: The WMD editor doesn't display code wrapped in < >. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you Try this

```
<List FeatureId="00BFEA71-DE22-43B2-A848-C05709900100" Type="100" Title="Simple List" Url="Lists/Simple List" />
```

I use this way. Feature Id is the ID of the Custom List Feature

Url is Must which is missing from your Code